# Matlab - Find index of a cell by its value

Tags: string, matlab, strcmp, cell-array

I have a cell array filedNames 11x1 in which each cell is a single string and I want to get the index of the cell which is equal to the string name.

I've found this example:

```
C = { {'a'}, {'b'}, {'c'}, {'a'}, {'a'} } % data
idx = find(strcmp([C{:}], 'a')) % single line engine
```

However when I apply it to my case:

```
find(strcmp([fieldNames{:}], 'b_h_epsQ_h'))
```

Nothing happens, and by itself strcmp([fieldNames{:}], 'b_h_epsQ_h') , doesn't find a match, although that If I type strcmp([fieldNames{2}], 'b_h_epsQ_h') the answer is 1.

I tied to transpose the cell array as the example is with 1x5 still no success

Comment: that example is a cell-array containing cell arrays (nested). Yours is just a cell array of strings. So try: `strcmp(fieldNames, 'b_h_epsQ_h')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
idx = strcmp(fieldNames, 'b_h_epsQ_h')
find(idx)
```

#### Example:

```
>> fieldNames = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
>> idx = strcmp(fieldNames, 'c')
idx =
     0     0     1     0     0
>> find(idx)
ans =
     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
idx = cellfun(@(x)strcmp(x,'c'), C);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
index = zeros(1,length(fieldNames))
for i = i:length(fieldNames)
    if find(strcmp([fieldNames{:}], 'b_h_epsQ_h')) == 1
        index[i] = 1
    end
end
```

If you want to immediately quit after you find the matching string, throw a 'break' in the 'if' clause after the 'index = i.'